# if a curve is asked and you are asked to find a specific value in that curve

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, implicit-differentiation

If a curve $y = f(x)$ passes through the point $(1, –1)$ and satisfies the differential equation, $y(1 + xy) dx = x dy$, then $f(-1/2)$ is equal to:

$$
\begin{align}
(1) & &4/5\\
(2) & &-2/5\\
(3) & &-4/5\\
(4) & &2/5
\end{align}
$$

$(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ and $(4)$ are the options. This is a multiple choice question.

My working:

$$ -d(x/y) = xdx $$

Till here I have found out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y=ux$ and $y(1 + xy) dx = x dy \Rightarrow uxdx+ux^3dx=uxdx+x^2du$

$uxdx+u^2x^3dx=uxdx+x^2du \Rightarrow u^2x^3dx=x^2du$

$u^2x^3dx=x^2du \Rightarrow x dx=\frac{du}{u^2}$

$x dx=\frac{du}{u^2} \Rightarrow \frac{x^2}{2}+c=\frac{-1}{u}$

$\frac{x^2}{2}+c=\frac{-1}{u} \Rightarrow y=\frac{-2x}{x^2+2c}$ and according to "$f(x)$ passes through the point $(1,-1)$"

$c=\frac{1}{2}$ so

$y=\frac{-2x}{x^2+1}$

so $f(-1/2)=4/5$

Comment: Well your answer is misleading me a little. Can you pls tell which option are you referring to

Comment: i am referring to (c) , as it can be found with calculating y for $x=-1/2$

Comment: well according to my records a is the correct answer

Comment: oh i have just realized you are right i am fixing it now thanks